# Open new tab jsp by calling a java method that returns the name of the jsp to open

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tabs

I'll explain better.
So I have in my jsp a button and onclick I call a java function

```
function goTo() {
document.forms['model'].action = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path...';
document.forms['model'].method = 'GET';
document.forms['model'].submit();
}
```

this one here, calls another java function which returns a String which is the name of the other jsp to open.

How can I manage to open that jsp in another tab? I tried window.open() on the button but it opens a blank page and on the first one the jsp it loads the new one. I tried to call window.open() on the .action but it tries to open a new page with the link "window.open(...path)"...

I'm struggling with this one. Any help?

Thank you all!

Comment: on submit you call java function what do you mean by that ? is that function is on same page ? or you redirect to some other page? how does you return string ?

Comment: I call a method in the controller that calls another method that returns the string. 
I simply retrieve the data I need for the new jsp and then add it to the new jsp, which is called by the string this method returns

Comment: so the new tab must be open on new jsp page? how does that page gets called ?

Comment: Yes.
I have `return new ModelAndView("redirect string to the jsp")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
After many tries, I've added

```
document.forms['model'].target = "_blank";
```